# How can I fix this Error (Entry1 not defined)

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started coding with Python and I can't find out how to fix the Error
(`NameError: name 'entry1' is not defined`)

```py
def forrangeright():
    entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
    entry1.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side="bottom")
    confirmi_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=confirmichars)
    confirmi_button.pack(padx=10, side="bottom", fill="x")


def confirmichars():
    customichars = entry1.get() < --- Error
    Herre
    print(customichars)
```

Comment: `entry1` is local to `forrangeright()` and is indeed not defined in `confirmichars()`.

Comment: Can you post the full code, please?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/besLtCHN

Answer (score 1):

`entry1.get()` is set in your function `forrangeright()` but not in `confirmichars()`

If you want to access to `entry1.get()` in `confirmichars()` you need to add `entry1.get()` in the function parameter like this:

```py
def confirmichars(entry1):
    customichars = entry1.get() < --- No Error Herre
    print(customichars)
```

Then you need to pass the argument so you can add a return to your function `forrangeright()` like this:

```py
def forrangeright():
    entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
    entry1.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side="bottom")
    confirmi_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=confirmichars)
    confirmi_button.pack(padx=10, side="bottom", fill="x")
    return entry1
```

Finally you can call your function `confirmichars(entry1)` like this:

```py
entry1 = forrangeright()
confirmichars(entry1)
```

Comment: Where do I have to put the "entry1 = forrangeright()
confirmichars(entry1)"

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that you use tkinter, try this in `forrangeright` :  `confirmi_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=confirmichars(entry1))`

Comment: 'def forrangeright():
        button1["text"] = "Custom"
        button2["text"] = "Custom"
        button2["command"] = ""
        button1["command"] = ""
        entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
        entry1.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side="bottom")
        confirmi_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=confirmichars(entry1))
        confirmi_button.pack(padx=10, side="bottom", fill="x")
        return entry1


def confirmichars(entry1):
        customichars = entry1.get()
        print(customichars)'

@Yannis Sauzeau No Error but nothing shoes up in the console

Comment: Sry I dont know how to make Code in a Comment

Comment: I found out why nothing shoes up -

The Function confirmichars is once called when the line "confirmi_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=confirmichars)" is executed.

But I want that the Function called when the button confirmi_button is pressed

Comment: Normally `command=confirmichars(entry1)` in your button calls the fonction `confirmichars(entry1)` when your button is pressed. I think your problem is in another part of your code..

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with **scope.**

A variable created inside a function belongs to the local scope of that function, and can only be used inside that function.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Here you define entry1 in the local scope of the forrangerright() function meaning that outside of that function entry1 is undefined.

You can either define entry1 outside of a function as a global variable (*bad practice*)

Or return entry1 from the forrangerright() function and pass it to confirmichars()

Here is an example:

```python
def forrangeright():
    entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
    entry1.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side="bottom")
    confirmi_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=confirmichars)
    confirmi_button.pack(padx=10, side="bottom", fill="x")
    return entry1

def confirmichars():
        entry1 = forrangeright()
        customichars = entry1.get()   <--- Error Herre
        print(customichars)
```

or pass entry1 as an argument

```python
def forrangeright():
    entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
    entry1.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side="bottom")
    confirmi_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=confirmichars)
    confirmi_button.pack(padx=10, side="bottom", fill="x")
    return entry1

def confirmichars(entry1):
        customichars = entry1.get()   <--- Error Herre
        print(customichars)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find out how to fix the Error (NameError: name 'entry1' is not
> defined)

Easier way to add `global` scope for both forrangeright() and confirmichars() functions.

Snippet:

```
def forrangeright():
        global entry1
        ...
        ...
```

and

```
def confirmichars():
        global entry1
        ...
        ...
```

Screenshot:

[image]

After that when DONE by clicking button. You see in debug window.